# Altering CT Volume voxel values in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to alter some voxel values in **Matlab**.

I am using the following code:

```
for p=1:100   
      Vol(Vol(:,:,p) > 0) = 65535; %altering voxel values in the volume to 65535 if value > 0.
end
```

Unfortunately, I find all the values being altered, as if the condition is not working, although if i write `Vol(Vol(:,:,1)>0)= 65535` immediately in the command line it works perfectly.

Any clue where the error is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why is because you are not indexing each slice properly in your volume.  When you are doing this `for` loop, what will happen is that the Boolean condition that is provided in `Vol` is modifying **only the first channel**.

Consider this small example.  Let's create a 3 x 3 x 3 matrix of all 1s.

```
A = ones(3,3,3)

A(:,:,1) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1


A(:,:,2) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1


A(:,:,3) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

Let's set the first slice all to 65535 according to your condition:

```
A(A(:,:,1) > 0) = 65535

A(:,:,1) =

   65535       65535       65535
   65535       65535       65535
   65535       65535       65535


A(:,:,2) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1


A(:,:,3) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

This certainly works as we expect.  Now let's try going to the second channel:

```
A(A(:,:,2) > 0) = 65535

A(:,:,1) =

   65535       65535       65535
   65535       65535       65535
   65535       65535       65535


A(:,:,2) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1


A(:,:,3) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

Oh no!  It didn't work!  It only worked for the first channel.... why?  The reason why is because `A(:,:,1)` or any other channel provides a **2D matrix**.  If you provide a single 2D matrix, it only modifies **the first slice** of the volume.  As such, as your loop keeps progressing, only the first channel gets modified (if at all).  If you wanted to modify the second channel, you would have to create a **3D matrix**, where the first slice would have all logical `false`, while the second slice contains the Boolean mask from `Vol(:,:,2) > 0`.

---

The 3D slicing stuff is probably complicated, especially for someone new to MATLAB.  As such, I would recommend you do this to make things simpler.  If you want to modify **each slice**, consider placing each binary mask as a temporary variable, modifying that temporary variable, then manually assigning this back to each slice.  In other words:

```
for p=1:100   
    temp = Vol(:,:,p); %//Extract p'th channel
    temp(temp > 0) = 65535; %// Find non-zero pixels and set to 65535
    Vol(:,:,p) = temp; %// Set back to p'th channel.
end
```

---

## Another recommended suggestion

Instead of using `for` loops, I would like to recommend this simple one-liner:

```
Vol(Vol > 0) = 65535;
```

This will automatically create a 3D `Boolean` matrix that will index `Vol`, and it will find those locations that are greater than 0, and set all of those locations to 65535.  This avoids the need of any unnecessary `for` loops.  This one-line essentially performs what the above `for` loop is doing, but is much more quicker... and I daresay much easier to read.

Comment: Many thanks for this thorough explanation...appreciate it :).       So,  that's why in some code they write Vol(:,:,1,p)....they create a fourth single channel?       It worked with me now and the first solution will help a lot when trying to threshold image by image.

Comment: @NohaSeada You're very welcome.  If this answer has helped, please consider accepting it.  Click on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, towards the left and below the up and down voting arrows.

Comment: hmm, shouldn't it be `A(A(:,:,2) > 0) = 65535` instead of `A(A(:,:,2) > 1) = 65535`? You kind of cheated there...

Comment: @m_power yes you're right but it still won't change the answer. I'll change it when I get to work. I was rapidly typing this up before I had to step out. If you have MATLAB, give the example a try with that corrected. You'll see the result is the same

Comment: @m_power - Corrected.  Thank you for the spot.

Comment: @NohaSeada - Yes.  In that case, the image is 4-dimensional.  As such, they are extracting the first **slice** of the p'th volume in the overall image.  The index of the fourth dimension would be referencing which volume you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, I would just do :

```
Vol(Vol(:,:,1:100) > 0) = 65535;
```

No need for loop.

Comment: This was also suggested in my post before I ended it.  Still, nice to see it without clutter here